# How to solve the parameters in Proximal Gradient Method?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent, proximal-operators

I know we use proximal gradient method for optimization problems like this:
$$\min_w f(w) = L(w) + R(w)$$
where $L(w)$ is convex and differentiable, but $R(w)$ is convex and not differentiable. If both of them were differentiable we could use a gradient descent method. A solution to this kind of problems is the proximal gradient method where the proximal operator is:
$$ prox_R(u) = argmin_w (R(w) + \frac{1}{2}\|w-u\|_2^2)$$
Then using function $f$ we linearize $L(w)$ at $w^k$:
$$w^{k+1} \in argmin_w(R(w) + L(w^k) + \nabla L(w^k)^T(w-w^k) + \frac{1}{2t_k}\|w-w^k\|_2^2$$
This can be simplified and results in:
$$(1) \text{ } w^{k+1} \in prox_{t_kT} (w^k-t_kg^k) = argmin_w(t_kR(w) + \frac{1}{2}\|w-w^k+t_kg^k\|_2^2$$
where $g^k:= \nabla L(w^k)$.
Therefore, in algorithm ISTA $w^{k+1}$ is computed by solving (1).

Now my question is the following:
**How are we going to solve $w_{k+1}$?** The proximal operator still contains $R(w)$ which is **not differentiable** and therefore we cannot get the minimal point using the gradient and setting it to zero?
Thus, what was the goal of using the proximal operator? In our script, it says that it is used for classes of functions which part of them are not differentiable and standard gradient descent does not work. But how has this reformulation helped us?

Answer (score 1):

There are many functions $R$ for which the proximal mapping can be computed explicitely, e.g., $\|\cdot\|_p$ for (at least) $p \in \{1,2,\infty\}$. I invite you to check these cases by hand (by using, e.g., the convex subdifferential).

Sometimes, such functions with an explicit proximal map are called 'proximable'. Many more such functions can be found at http://proximity-operator.net.